# Password sign-in blocked by installed software

Tags: login, password

Yesterday I installed Gnome-do and today it is completely blocking my password sign-in form. Which of course means I can't do anything at all. I know this is my own fault, and yes I'm a dumb noob, but now I can't use my own computer. 
Gnome-do is apparently running at startup (as soon as I try to regain access to my desktop, it is gone) and its "type to search" box is physically covering the sign in box. I cannot do anything at all!
I've tried restarting, I can't access terminal, or anything else. I don't want to do anything to mess things up.

Comment: Hit `Ctrl Alt F1`, you'll get to a Terminal. Login. Run `sudo apt remove gnome-do` to remove gnome-do. Restart (by running `sudo reboot`). Login, this time to the GUI.

Comment: My above comment is just a temporary fix, the main issue is controlling Gnome-Do's startup.

Comment: Maybe the box can be removed by pressing `Esc`?

Comment: Thank you. I have access to my desktop now. I will be removing Gnome-do. But no, ESC didn't work. I had to restart and boot from command line. To be honest I'm not entirely sure what I did. But it worked. Again, thank you for responding so quickly.

Comment: Also, if you want a launcher like Gnome-Do, look at Synapse and Kupfer.

Comment: Or Launchy, that's a great alternative too.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to recreate this issue but as Bharadwaj Raju suggested you can use `Ctrl ALT F1` to enter a terminal then remove gnome-do .. then once booted back in, if you want to use the program still .. you can install it and run it then click the triangle in the upper right and select preferences. In the general tab select `Hide window on first launch (quiet mode)` This should "hide" it at login so you should be able to avoid your issue.

Since I can't recreate the issue and if I set it to start at login, for me, it starts after I login (but I tested this on 16.04 Unity), I can't be sure that this will solve your issue or not. If it doesn't you can always remove it again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to fix it:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Then you will be greeted by a terminal prompt. Now type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-do
```

This will remove gnome-do and your login problem is now fixed.

To reboot, type:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

That's it! You should be able to login into your account without any problems.